# Error using QVectorIterator

Tags: c++, qt

I have a strange problem with a [QVectorIterator](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qvectoriterator.html#QVectorIterator)

I try the example they provide:

```
 QVector<float> vector;
 QVectorIterator<float> i(vector);
 while (i.hasNext())
     qDebug() << i.next();
```

but it won't compile,
it says :

> vector is not a type

.
Do you know why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You probably have something like:

```
using namespace std;
```

above. As part of std namespace there's templated class `std::vector` so your declaration causes nameclash since you are trying to name your variable with name already used by class. To solve it either remove `using namespace std` (but then you would need to always fully qualify everything from std namespace) or just choose some other name for your variable.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but I don't use namespace std, and I tried to give another name to the vector, but it didn't work... for example   
QVector<int> v;
QVectorIterator<int> iterator(v);
didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show us some real example not just snippet? Also don't forget that it don't need to be directly that source file, that using can be also in any header file included from that cpp file.

When you renamed the variable from vector to v, what was the error message then?

Comment: "using" in a header would be particularly bad style though. (and yes, what's the error with v?)

Comment: In fact, I don't have any real example to provide because it is not working, but I'll try to explain what I'm doing :
I have an enum with different states (state1, state2, state3) called _state_. I create a QVector of  _state_ (for example state3, state1, state2), i.e the order. And then, I want to have an iterator on this vector to be able to say "next" (until no more state). Is it clear ?
And when I change the name, it says "v is not a type"